# Fingerprint reader stopped working after motherboard replaced

Tags: lenovo, fingerprint-reader

I have a 6-month-old Lenovo T14s Gen 3 (Intel) laptop, with Ubuntu 22.04.2. It died suddenly, so Lenovo replaced the motherboard.  Now the fingerprint reader won't allow me to record prints.  I have done a "factory reset" of the fingerprint reader in the BIOS. I've also (before that) tried deleting all records using fprintd.

But now/still, when I run "fprintd-enroll", I get:

```
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
```

and then it waits. I touch the fingerprint reader and immediately it aborts with:

```
Enroll result: enroll-disconnected
```

Same if I specify a different finger.

`sudo lshw` shows this, but I can't see a fingerprint reader

```
 *-input:7
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 9
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       capabilities: platform
```

I can't see anything fingerprint-related in `ls -l /dev` either.

In `sudo journalctl -b 0` I found this, which I think are simply where authentication is choosing not to use it in favor of a typed password(??):

```
Jul 06 09:14:39 mylaptop gdm-fingerprint][19449]: gkr-pam: no password is available for user
```

and these:

```
Jul 06 09:14:39 mylaptop dbus-daemon[1084]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 06 09:15:21 mylaptop systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 06 09:15:54 mylaptop dbus-daemon[1084]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.403' (uid=0 pid=20057 comm="sudo ls " label="unconfined")
Jul 06 09:15:54 mylaptop dbus-daemon[1084]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 06 09:16:24 mylaptop systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 06 10:40:36 mylaptop dbus-daemon[1084]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.488' (uid=0 pid=26032 comm="sudo lshw " label="unconfined")
Jul 06 10:40:36 mylaptop dbus-daemon[1084]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 06 10:41:12 mylaptop systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 06 10:58:07 mylaptop dbus-daemon[1084]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' unit='fprintd.service' requested by ':1.518' (uid=0 pid=27798 comm="sudo fprintd-enroll " label="unconfined")
Jul 06 10:58:07 mylaptop dbus-daemon[1084]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 06 10:58:10 mylaptop sudo[27798]:     meuser : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/meuser/linux/T14sG3I ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/fprintd-enroll
Jul 06 10:58:14 mylaptop fprintd[27799]: identify has failed: 502
Jul 06 10:58:14 mylaptop fprintd[27799]: Device reported an error during identify for enroll: Unexpected result from device 502
Jul 06 10:58:45 mylaptop systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

By the way, every second, a message like this is going to the journal:

```
Jul 06 11:04:31 mylaptop kernel: i2c_designware i2c_designware.1: controller timed out
```

If there's a hardware issue, Lenovo would be willing to help/fix it. But it seems to recognize that I've touched it, so I think everything must be connected. How can I get it working?

Comment: Look at the system startup logs. You can watch your system detecting your hardware, including the fingerprint reader with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man less journalctl`.

Comment: Look at `sudo lshw`. Read `man lshw`

Comment: Look at the fingerprint reader's "owner", "group", and permission bits with `ls -l /dev`. Use `id` to see if you have membership in the same group. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment.